# How to use cairo to draw custom controls on Linux wxWidgets as with GDI+ on Windows wxWidgets?

Tags: render, codeblocks, wxwidgets, cairo

On Windows using Code::Blocks, I used to call this->GetHandle() in a wxWidgets custom control to obtain a HWND handle from where to draw with GDI+ libraries. In Linux doing the same I get a GtkWidget* when I call this->GetHandle() from a paint event handler, but I don't know how to use cairo libraries as with GDI+ to render the custom control. I try some examples of cairo rendering from the internet, but honestly didn't work.

In the custom control I have this in the paint event handler

```
void WorkingArea::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& event)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}
```

The render function is this

```
void WorkingArea::render(wxDC& dc)
{
     Render(this->GetHandle(),graph);
    //In windows I just call Render((HWND)this->GetHandle(),graph);
}
```

In Windows the Render function is as follow

```
void Render(HWND window_handle,const Simple2DGraph& graph)
{
    delete gw;//deletes window graphic
    gw=Graphics::FromHWND(window_handle);
    delete g;     //deletes buffer bitmap graphic
    delete buffer;//deletes the buffer bitmap
    ctrlW=graph.getCtrlW();
    ctrlH=graph.getCtrlH();
    buffer=new Bitmap(ctrlW,ctrlH,gw);
    g=Graphics::FromImage(buffer);
    //Graphics buffer settings
    g->SetCompositingMode(CompositingMode::CompositingModeSourceOver);
    g->SetCompositingQuality(CompositingQuality::CompositingQualityHighSpeed);
    g->SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationMode::InterpolationModeBicubic);
    g->SetPageScale(1);
    g->SetPageUnit(Unit::UnitPixel);
    g->SetPixelOffsetMode(PixelOffsetMode::PixelOffsetModeHighSpeed);
    g->SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingMode::SmoothingModeHighQuality);
    g->SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHint::TextRenderingHintSystemDefault);
    g->Clear(color1);
    //->
    //->
    //->
    //More rendering commands
}
```

Where I used the passed HWND to create a windows graphics where I  draw objects with the GDI+ library. I would like to know how to use the cairo library methods to render the custom control from the obtained GtkWidget* as I can do on Windows using the GDI+ graphics created by the passed HWND.

Comment: Did you try wxGraphicsContext, wxRendererNative?

Comment: Yes, I did try those too. The code create the cairo_t and everything but render nothing on the screen. It only shows a blank white window.

Comment: Build and run `drawing` sample that comes with wxW. Open `Drawing` menu and choose `Use default wxGraphicsContext`. Do you see there a blank white window too?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? I.e. surely your final goal is not to "use Cairo" but actually draw something, isn't it? If this is the case, you should just use `wxGraphicsContext` as already advised in a comment.

If not, you basically need to use GTK API directly, there are plenty of examples of using Cairo together with GTK. But, again, this goes against the whole idea of using wxWidgets to hide the differences between the platforms -- which is exactly what `wxGraphicsContext` does (as it uses GDI+ or Direct2D internally under Windows and Cairo under Unix systems).

Comment: I tried your solution, but it just don't work. I'm using code::blocks in a wxWidgets project to make a gui. When I get the GtkWidget* from GetHandle (remember I'm using Linux) It do nothing, no matter if I use wxGraphicsContext or another way

Comment: I think the solution has to do with event signaling in GTK, so how do I to rebind the signals and function callbacks for painting the widget?

Comment: With wxWidgets you paint from `wxEVT_PAINT` handler. If you don't want to use wxWidgets for this window, you should implement it at GTK level completely and embed it using `wxNativeWindow`. It's still not clear at all what are you actually trying to do.

Comment: It's simple, I'm using wxWidgets to do regular GUI like menus and buttons, but I need a single custom control that has a very complex drawing and composition. That single control I intending to drawing it all from the native API in each OS (GDI+ in Windows and GTK+ in Linux) and starting from the handle that is returned in the GetHandle method of the wxWidgets objects. The solutions that have been commented for some reason don't work, and beside that I need to use the functionality of save and restore the graphics state in order to save time in the rendering.

Comment: I have to add, the control is far more complex than a custom button with a different shape but more simple than lets say a game. The application is intended to run in an machine with no GPU so I need to do the best I can with GDI+ and GTK+ APIs

Comment: The unclear thing is why can't you do this using `wxGraphicsContext` and have to go down to the native API directly. But I agree that using `GetHandle()` should still work. I don't know why it doesn't, sorry. As always, starting with a minimal simplest possible and self-contained example would be a good first step.